# Why comparing objects and array of objects is different

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, compare

Why when I compare

```
var a = {id: 1, status: true};
var b = {id: 1, status: true};
console.log(a == b);
```

it returns `false`

and when I compare

```
var array1 = [{id: 1, status: true}, {id:1, status: true}];
var array2 = [{id: 1, status: true}, {id:1, status: true}];
console.log(array1[0] == array2[0]);
```

it returns `false`

But when I compare

```
var a = {id: 1, status: true};
var b = {id: 1, status: true};
var array1 = [a, b];
var array2 = [a, b];
console.log(array1[0] == array2[0]);
```

it returns `true`?

Comment: Because in last case, reference is same `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` checks operands references. `array1` and `array2` have different references. But `array1[0]` and `array2[0]` have both the same reference (`a`), so `array1[0] == array2[0]` returns `true`.

Comment: So `array1[0] === array2[0]` should return false? Cause it doesn't

Comment: No it should return true. The have the exact same reference (a)

Comment: I think I understood, it is comparing the reference not the object, correct?

Comment: Exactly, it compares the reference and not the instances value

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing two identical, but different, objects. Which will and should return false. If you want it to return true it should look like:

```
var a = {id: 1, status: true};
var b = a;
console.log(a == b);
```

It doesn't really matter if they are in an array or not. The same applies for arrays. If you compare two arrays it will return false even if they are identical unless the variables point to the same array.